# Fee quotation form just below the first fold. Are we losing orders?

Tags: website-design, navigation, user-behavior, design-patterns

Our site has a fee quotation form below the fold and we are concerned that we may be losing potential customers. What evidence is there that the "fold" is still a concern?

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the form itself rather than if it's above or below the fold. Even better, show prices up front if possible rather than asking people to request a quote in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

the fold myth is just that, a myth. If you need references, here you have:

- [Scrolling and Attention](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/scrolling-and-attention/)
- [Myth #3: People don’t scroll](http://uxmyths.com/post/654047943/myth-people-dont-scroll)
- [Why “The Fold” Is A Myth – And Where To Actually Put Your Calls To Action](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/why-the-fold-is-a-myth/)
- [Fold or Scroll: Above and Beyond the Web Design Myth](http://www.oliverrussell.com/better-user-experience-above-the-fold-ui)
- [Stop the Above The Fold Web Design Insanity - People Scroll Today!!!!!](https://www.nuvonium.com/blog/view/stop-the-above-the-fold-web-design-insanity-people-scroll-today)

## HOWEVER...

From the first link by Nielsen:

> **But no, the fact that users scroll doesn't free you from prioritizing
>   and making sure that anything truly important remains above the fold.**

Which means: just because people scrolls doesn't mean you shouldn't prioritize your content. **Which doesn't mean to place everything above the fold!** (**nor the opposite!**). It means you need to use the right tools to achieve the perfect result, and these tools includes researching and testing.

For example, you can place your neat form on top, yet I have no idea what the product is about, **why would I want to fill your form if I have no idea what it takes?**. Now I scroll and scroll and scroll.... and I lost focus from your form. Can you say your form was well placed?

On the other side, let's say I engage the user to continue reading and creating a sense of anticipation, leading the user to where I want with visual, contextual and copy techniques. But the time s/he reaches the end of the page, I'll have 50% of the sale done, I just need a good CTA **EXACTLY WHERE I STOPPED ENTICING THE USER** . This could be (usually is) 5, 6 or even 10 scrolls down. **Which placement do you think will work the best?** I know it for a fact because I have tested it no less than 500 times and results really leave no room for doubts or interpretation.

## In short

To answer your question: Not only **above the fold** is a myth, but usually a nonsensical lie. However, the placement of your CTA can't be based on the truth or falsity of this premise, it would be like considering a technology approach based on people having IBM-400 computers at home. Could happen, but really, you have more important things to worry about. So **test your specific scenario and drag your own conclusions, then adjust as needed**

Answer (score 0):

The fold is not so black and white
https://www.hugeinc.com/ideas/perspective/everybody-scrolls

> UX designers are divided about how essential above-the-fold placement – that is, positioning so that users can see content without scrolling down – really is. Chartbeat found that “66% of attention on a normal media page is spent below the fold.” In contrast, the Nielsen Norman Group showed that “users spend 80% of their time looking above the fold.”
>
> **We learned that participants almost always scrolled**, regardless of how they are cued to do so – and that’s liberating. While it’s hard to make universal recommendations, we’d suggest that designers use the cue that works best in its context.

Comment: Hey welcome to UX.se, could you please take some of the relevant content from the linked website and include it in your answer. Link only answers are frowned upon here because if that linked article were to disappear this answer would no longer provide any information. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you are right the free quotation form is below the fold of the homepage. You need to drag it above so that users can directly come and see the form to place an order. The other aspects of the screen are fine.